# How to output individual files without subfolder with ParcelJS 2?

Tags: parceljs

I'm using Parcel 2. I have set up a folder structure for separate JS and Scss files. I can get Parcel to bundle them and output the files, however, they end up in a subfolder. I want the files to be in the root of the output folder.

Structure:

- assets (dir)
- styles (dir)

  - templates
  - sections
  - index.scss
- scripts (dir)

  - templates
  - sections
  - index.js

I want both *index* files to make it into the root of the *assets* folder, but when I run Parcel I end up with this:

- assets

  - styles

    - index.css
  - scripts

    - index.js

I've tried many different variations of the command, but so far none will drop the files into the root of *assets*. Any ideas?

This is the current command from my package.json file:

```
"dev": "parcel styles/index.scss scripts/index.js --dist-dir assets"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out. Replying in case someone else runs into the same thing.

I created a new dir called Parcel and moved everything into it. Then I moved both index files into the root of Parcel. Then I ran `npm run dev` from the root of the Parcel folder. I was then getting the individual scss and js files outputted to the root of my assets dir.

- Assets
- Parcel

  - Styles

    - Global
    - Product
    - Collection
  - Scripts

    - Global
    - Product
    - Collection
  - index.scss
  - index.js

Note: after I got this working I ran into another issue where the js file that got outputted was empty. As of the writing of this post I haven't been able to fix that yet.